# How can I show a String for a certain seconds

Tags: android, string, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I got a question.
How can I show a string for only a certain time , and then the the textview changes the string.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: What do you wanna achieve? How is the String changed?

Comment: Start a Thread e.g. `AsyncTask`, that sleeps a while and then does the change.

Comment: this is not a real question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a timer to set text

```
   _tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
    _t = new Timer();
    -tv.setText("hi");
    _t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                _count++;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
                 {
                  public void run() 
                  { 

                     if(_count==5)//after 5 seconds change the text
                     {
                       _tv.setText("hello");
                     }
                 }
                 });
            }
        }, 1000, 1000 );
```

Remember to cancel the timer when done.

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
            cdt =  (new CountDownTimer(5000,1000){ // 5 seconds
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){

            }

            public void onFinish(){
                TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
                t.setText("Here is the new text");
            }
        }.start());
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `Handler.onPostDelayed()`.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, especially for yours bflosabre91 this was what I needed.

Comment: @Marques if this is the correct answer then accept it, So it can help others